# calculate partial derivatives

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the function

$$f(x,y)=  \begin{cases} \frac{(x^3y-y^3x)}{(x^2+y^2)}, &(x,y)\ne(0,0) \\ & \\0, & (x,y)=(0,0) \end{cases}  $$

I want calculate $$\frac{\partial f^2}{\partial x\partial y} (0,0). $$

I think that$$\frac{\partial f^2}{\partial x\partial y} (0,0)={\partial_y(\partial_xf (0,0))=lim_{t->0}{{\partial_xf (0,t) }-{\partial_xf (0,0) })\over t }}$$

$${\partial_xf (0,0) }=0 $$ and $$\partial_xf (0,t)=-t$$ then $${\partial_{xy}^2f (0,0) }=-1$$It's right?

Comment: Yes > Nothing wrong there.

Comment: why  $\partial _x f (0,0)=0$ ?

Comment: Looks fine, except that you should also explain how you found $\partial_x f$.

Comment: $lim_{t->0}{(f(t,0)-f(0,0))\over t}$=$lim_{t->0} {{0}\over{t^3}}=0 $